# Can't access localhost via IPv4 - but IPv6 works

Tags: windows-10, networking, ip, http, localhost

I can't access 127.0.0.1 or my own IPv4 address (192.168.178.xx) in any browser, while the IPv6 address [::1] works.

More information:

- My OS is Windows 10 Pro 20H2 19042.985.
- Pinging 127.0.0.1 and my own IP address (192.168.178.xx) works.
- I run an Apache2 and a Node server in WSL2. Neither of them work with 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.178.xx, but both work with [::1] and with WSL IPv4 address 172.22.239.xx.
- There's nothing special in my hosts file, just an entry for an Apache virtual host and standard additions from Docker Desktop. I also tried different configurations for localhost by now, but without effect.

I am not sure when this issue started. A few weeks ago I started to get two problems which I didn't connect at first:

- I couldn't reach Apache2 via localhost on Firefox (I now know that's because Firefox uses IPv4 unlike Chrome).
- I couldn't reach my PC via IPv4 from my iPhone.

Both worked before. Now after some research and coincidental findings I think I narrowed it down to the above described issue. I can't remember making any system changes during the time the problems arose. It really came out of nowhere for me.

The issue seems quite similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543443/cant-access-127-0-0-1 But unlike described there my own IPv4 address does not work. And unfortunately the accepted solution did not work for me.